# How should I keep temporary data for socket.io interactions in node.js?

Tags: node.js, database, memory, socket.io, relational-database

I am building a simple game in node.js using socket.io. My web experience with node.js has typically involved saving everything to a relational database and keeping nothing in memory. I set up a relational database for the state of a game. I am using sqlite3 for development and I might use something like PostgreSQL or MySQL for production.

My concern is that, every time an event is emitted from the socket the whole game-state is loaded into memory from the server. I feel that in practice this will be less efficient than just keeping all of the game-state data in memory. Events will probably be emitted every 5 seconds or so during a game. All of the game data is temporary, none of it will be needed after the game is over. A game-state consists of a set of about 120 groups of small strings and integers (about 10 per group but subject to change).

Is it good practice to keep this type of data in memory?

If not, should I stick with relational databases or switch to a third option like a file-based storage structure?

Should I not load the whole gamestate in for every event even though that will lead to a lot more read/writes (at least triple)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like relational, SQL type database is a huge overhead for your specifics. Do you have idea how big your data is and how many users you'd like to handle? Then you could compare it with your's server ability. If result is negative (couldn't handle with mem) - then i'd go with some quick nosql, like mongo. For yours example its sounds like the best choice. It'll be faster to get data for single session, easier to dump, more elastic in structure.

Comment: The games will be relatively small and I have no idea how many users I will have.

Comment: Then i'd go for some nosql. From my experiences it sounds best for projects like yours. Kind of hard to implement for huge data demanding application with multiple relations. But best for projects like yours. Of course it all depends on many variables, but that's all I can tell basing on data you've provided.

Comment: I was thinking about just using memory for development then scaling to nosql or a cache. Do you think that makes sense? Would nosql be better than something like Redis?

Comment: well that depends on your project. If you'd like to only store information like you've said then yes Redis would be beter. If you'd like also to store some user information for longer time then you'd go with nosql. Best option to go with redis + some db. But its a biggie.

Comment: I was planning on going relational for account information. Also subject to change but that will be accessed much less frequently and I am more comfortable with that type of data. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would not keep this data in the memory of your NodeJS application. Its best avoid storing state in your app server. If you really need faster read access than sql provides consider using a cache like Redis or Memcached as a layer between your app and db.

All that being said its best not to prematurely optimize you code. Most SQL engines have their own form of cacheing, and optimizing your sql queries is a better place to start if your experiencing performance issues. [Postgresql Query Optimization](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html)

But don't worry about it until its an actual problem (because most likely it never will be).

Comment: I am thinking about this more in terms of ease of development at the moment. Using a relational database will be much more involved than using memory. I would be happy to do it but if it ends up not being the right choice than I will have wasted my time. I am thinking of going memory for development and switching to nosql or a cache if that becomes too much.